# How to load spring mvc template from multiple locations?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a spring-mvc project with configured to load template from WEB-INF/jsp, and I use the Servlet 3.0 property that load some mvc template from **WEB-INF/lib/someplugins.jar!/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp/a.jsp**, How can I do this?

this spring configuration for view resolver that I have is

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own view resolver by extending InternalResourceViewResolver and customize the `buidView(String viewName)` method.

```
public class TemplateViewResolver extends InternalResourceViewResolver {

    @Override
    protected AbstractUrlBasedView buildView(String viewName) throws Exception {
         String otherViewName = /* Custom lookup logic */;
         return super.buildView(otherViewName);
    }
}
```